# Expandable List View android

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm working on an application which will display some expandable lists. The fact is sometimes the object won't have any child. So I would like to display in my expandable list only elements which have childs. 
I tried to put an if inside the getGroupView function and if the object has no child, I return null but I get a nullPointerException error...

Here is the function:

```
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    // Check if the object as child
    System.out.println("Result list :: " + mParent.get(i).getListe());

            if(mParent.get(i).getListe().isEmpty()){
        return null;
    }

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_parent, viewGroup,false);
    }



    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
    //"i" is the position of the parent/group in the list
    textView.setText(getGroup(i).toString());

    // Set the Image View with the brand logo
    ImageView logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.brandlogo);

    // Set image Source
    logo.setImageResource(mParent.get(i).getLogoPath());

    // Set Image size       
    logo.getLayoutParams().height = 42;
    logo.getLayoutParams().width = 226;

    //return the entire view
    return view;
}
```

Is there a way do skip this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getGroupCount()` function return the number of items with childes (number of items has childes).
And in `getGroubView()` return the correct view (never return a `null` here).

Comment: the view that has a child at that position

Comment: but if the group as no child what do i return?

Comment: In getGroupCount you calculate the number of views with childes, lets say you have 3 items (1 and 3 have childes) 2 haven’t. getGroupCount must return 2, and for getGroubView with position 0 return view number 1, for getGroubView with position 1 return view number 3

Comment: I agree with you but let's say we are at the position 1, I return the view number 3 by doing i++? and if I do that, in case of a fourth element, the position 2 should return the fourth element, but it will return the 3 no?

Comment: if you return 2 in getGroupCount() function the getGroubView() will called only for two position 0 and 1. so you dont need to worry about 3rd position. and you need to make some logic here dont use i++

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27041/discussion-between-jafarkhq-and-guillaume-le-floch)

Comment: Yeah but let's say we have 4 items( 1,3 and 4 have childs) 2 haven't.So the getGroupCount will return 3. getGroupView with position 0 will return the number 1, for the position 1, I'll skip the elements by doing i++ so I'll get the number 3 for the position 2 and finally for the position 3, I'll get the number 3 and not the number 4 right? that's my problem... My arrayList is not sorted.. So elements with no childs can be anywhere in the list...

Comment: make some logic in getGroup(groupPosition) function dont use i++, somthing like, item = list.get(position); if(!item.hasChiled()) item = list.get(position+1); ... etc return item